# Can't build the angular 2 github project

Tags: angularjs, angular, gulp

I have forked the angular 2 github repo, clone it in my desktop, add upstream then run npm install, but when I want to build ($(npm bin)/gulp build) i have an error message:

> "Task 'build' is not in your gulpfile"

How can I properly build the project?

Answer (score 1):

Try `gulp build.sh` for more recent versions. You can also run simply `./build.sh` from the base directory. For future reference you can see a list of gulp tasks using `gulp -T`.

Make sure you're using the correct version of node (use nvm if you need to) as described in the [developer guide](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md).